# ValueError: logits and targets must have the same shape (tf.learn, DNNLinearCombinedClassifier)

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to train the ['Wide & Deep Learning'](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/wide_and_deep/index.html) model on my own datasets, and this error occurs when I fit the model to the training set.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-8f5351c1fdf8> in <module>()
----> 1 m.fit(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=200)

/Users/prisma/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.pyc in fit(self, x, y, input_fn, steps, batch_size, monitors, max_steps)
331                              steps=steps,
332                              monitors=monitors,
--> 333                              max_steps=max_steps)
334     logging.info('Loss for final step: %s.', loss)
335     return self

/Users/prisma/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.pyc in _train_model(self, input_fn, steps, feed_fn, init_op, init_feed_fn, init_fn, device_fn, monitors, log_every_steps, fail_on_nan_loss, max_steps)
660       features, targets = input_fn()
661       self._check_inputs(features, targets)
--> 662       train_op, loss_op = self._get_train_ops(features, targets)
663 
664       # Add default monitors.

/Users/prisma/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn_linear_combined.pyc in _get_train_ops(self, features, targets)
188     logits = self._logits(features, is_training=True)
189     if self._enable_centered_bias:
--> 190       centered_bias_step = [self._centered_bias_step(targets, features)]
191     else:
192       centered_bias_step = []

/Users/prisma/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn_linear_combined.pyc in _centered_bias_step(self, targets, features)
272     with ops.name_scope(None, "centered_bias", (targets, features)):
273       training_loss = self._target_column.training_loss(
--> 274           logits, targets, features)
275     # Learn central bias by an optimizer. 0.1 is a convervative lr for a
276     # single variable.

/Users/prisma/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/target_column.pyc in training_loss(self, logits, target, features, name)
204     """
205     target = target[self.name] if isinstance(target, dict) else target
--> 206     loss_unweighted = self._loss_fn(logits, target)
207 
208     weight_tensor = self.get_weight_tensor(features)

/Users/prisma/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/target_column.pyc in _log_loss_with_two_classes(logits, target)
387     target = array_ops.expand_dims(target, dim=[1])
388   loss_vec = nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits,
--> 389                                                   math_ops.to_float(target))
390   return loss_vec
391 

/Users/prisma/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn.pyc in sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, targets, name)
432     except ValueError:
433       raise ValueError("logits and targets must have the same shape (%s vs %s)"
--> 434                        % (logits.get_shape(), targets.get_shape()))
435 
436     # The logistic loss formula from above is

ValueError: logits and targets must have the same shape ((?, 1) vs (13647309, 24))
```

I can't figure out why the logits are of shape (?,1) instead of (13647309, 24). The input_fn function should return a feature dict of size (13647309, 24) and a label tensor of shape (13647309, 24). As far as I'm concerned, the logits should be the outputs from the model, but there's no where in the DNNLinearCombinedClassifier to specify the output size, so that I assume the outputs size are automatically adjusted to be the same as the label size, which is (13647309, 24). I don't know why this error occurs, but I guess there's something wrong with my model. Since the entire codes are too long to be pasted, I'll just paste the model construction part here.

```
model_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
m = tf.contrib.learn.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier(
    model_dir=model_dir,
    linear_feature_columns=wide_columns,
    dnn_feature_columns=deep_columns,
    dnn_hidden_units=[100, 50])
```

I didn't change the parameters of the model from tensorflow tutorial. I just defined the 'wide_columns' and 'deep_columns' in terms of my own dataset. Is there something wrong with the model or my input function?  I can't find the reference of DNNLinearCombinedClassifier on tf.learn api website.

**Update:** codes for the input function

```
def input_fn(df):
  continuous_cols = {k: tf.constant(df[k].values)
                     for k in CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS}

  categorical_cols = {k: tf.SparseTensor(
      indices=[[i, 0] for i in range(df[k].size)],
      values=df[k].values,
      shape=[df[k].size, 1])
                      for k in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS}

  feature_cols = dict(continuous_cols.items() + categorical_cols.items())

  label = tf.constant(df[Label_COLUMNS].values)

  return feature_cols, label
```

There are 24 channels in 'Label_COLUMNS'.

Comment: Can you show ur code for input_fn?

Comment: Sure. I've added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have to specify `n_classes=24` in `DNNLinearCombinedClassifier`'s constructor. See [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn_linear_combined.py#L606) for documentation.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I need!